# Find a matrix representation of T with respect to the basis vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not quite sure how to entirely solve this problem.

Find the matrix representation of the linear map: $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, (x, y) \to (2y, 3x-y)$ be relative to the following bases: $\alpha = \{(1, 0), (0,1)\}$ and $\beta = \{(1,3), (2,5)\}$.

This is how I approached the problem:

$T(\alpha_1) = (0, 3)$ and $T(\alpha_2) = (2, -1)$.

Now I need to solve $T(\alpha_1) = k_1\beta_1 + k_2\beta_2$, $T(\alpha_2) = m_1\beta_1 + m_2\beta_2$ and  but I am not sure if this is the right procedure. In fact, I am not sure I completely understand why I am doing this. Any help appreciated. The scalars are then placed as column vectors in the matrix $[T]_\alpha^\beta$.

Comment: Your procedure is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, your values are:  $m_1=-12$, $m_2=7$, $k_1=6$ and $k_2=-3$. Replacing your vectors for the second basis $\beta_1=(1,3)$ and $\beta_2=(2,5)$ in

$$(0,3)=T(1,0)=T(\alpha_1) = k_1\beta_1 + k_2\beta_2$$

$$(2,-1)=T(0,1)=T(\alpha_2) = m_1\beta_1 + m_2\beta_2$$

this will give you:

$$(0,3)=T(\alpha_1) = k_1(1,3) + k_2(2,5)=(k_1+2k_2,3k_1+5k_2)$$

$$(2,-1)=T(\alpha_2) = m_1(1,3) + m_2(2,5)=(m_1+2m_2,3m_1+5m_2)$$

developing the linear combinations you get two linear systems for the $k$ and $m$ unknowns:

$$ k_1+2k_2=0 $$ 
$$ 3k_1+5k_2=3 $$

and

$$ m_1+2m_2=2 $$
$$ 3m_1+5m_2=-1 $$
you must get the values I wrote above.Finally, your matrix shoud be the following:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} \ 6 & -12\\ -3&\ 7\end{array}\right)$$

In general, if you want to solve for $k_1$, $k_2$, $m_1$ and $m_2$ you can do the following steps:

Consider an augmented matrix with the columns you mentioned:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}  
 1 & 2 & \ z\\  
 3 & 5 & \ w  
\end{array}\right)$$

and then apply Guass-Jordan method. First, multiply by $-3$ the first row and add this result to the second row to get:
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}  
 1 & 2 & \ z\\  
 0 & -1 & \ w-3z  
\end{array}\right)$$
Multiply by $-1$ the second row:
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}  
 1 & 2 & \ z\\  
 0 & 1 & \ 3z-w  
\end{array}\right)$$
Multiply the second row by $-2$ and add the result to the first row to get:
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}  
 1 & 0 & \ z-2(3z-w)\\  
 0 & 1 & \ 3z-w  
\end{array}\right)$$
This give you
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}  
 1 & 0 & \ -5z+2w\\  
 0 & 1 & \ 3z-w  
\end{array}\right)$$
So, when you replace $(z,w)=(0,3)$ in the last matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}  
 1 & 0 & \ \ 6\\  
 0 & 1 & \ -3  
\end{array}\right)$$
you get the values of $k_1=6$ and $k_2=-3$.

When you replace $(z,w)=(2,-1)$ in the same matrix we replaced above you will get:
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}  
 1 & 0 & \ -12 \\  
 0 & 1 & \ 7 
\end{array}\right)$$
so $m_1=-12$ and $m_2=7$.

Comment: How did you solve for them?

Comment: @TimelordViktorious: Look to  the update I made in the answer. The procedure you talk about is the completely right. You just have to finish it replacing the vector for the second basis.

Comment: I just don't get how you solved for $k_1$, $k_2$, etc... Did you put something into a matrix and row reduced?

Comment: @TimelordViktorious: You can do it by hand, directly. No need to row reduce the 2x2 matrix. Do it directly by hand if you want. Of course, if you prefer to do row reduction you will get the same answer.

Comment: @TimelordViktorious: For instance, I take one fo the equations for the $k$'s I isolate one variable and then I replace the rhs in the other equation.

Comment: Hmm. Still a bit confused how to solve in a matrix. I put (1, 2) and (3,5) as column vectors and set it equal to (0,3). I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: @TimelordViktorious: Ok, I show you, Give me 5min to update. You will see how to reduce the matrix you are talking about to solve for $k_1$, $k_2$, $m_1$ and $m_2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67926/discussion-between-hector-blandin-and-timelordviktorious).

Comment: It's done. You can check the calculations to see how to find the m's and the k's.